# Show amendments to a commit

Tags: git, version-control

If I've done git commit --amend several times on the same commit, is there a way I can list all of the different amendments to a given commit?

Comment: Take a look at `git reflog`. But this log is not permanent and gets purged regularly.

Answer (score 23):

Actually the way exists. You can use the command `git reflog`

```
$ git reflog 
d7f7f15 HEAD@{0}: commit (amend): My second commit
f5d2ed5 HEAD@{1}: commit (amend): My second commit
7333d86 HEAD@{2}: commit: My second commit
addbfef HEAD@{3}: commit: This was my first commit
```

When I use the pugin EGIT in the IDE Eclipse I can see the full list of commits and amendments, and the differences between them. I don't know how to see the differences by command line, if someone know how to do it, please post it.

Comment: thanks, very helpful. You can then show a particular file content from original "My second commit" with "git show 7333d86:relative_filepath_from_project_folder"

Comment: How can I see dates of these commits? git log --reflog shows the same date for all amendments.

Comment: simply `git diff HEAD@{1}` to see differences only made in the last amendment; `git diff HEAD@{2} HEAD@{3}`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`git commit --amend` rewrites the commit completely, creating a new commit object and ultimately throwing the old one away. If there are references to the old object it is kept, so you could look up the changes; but in general this will probably not the case.

So the short answer is: No. Amending commits will rewrite the original commit to explicitely *not* have separated history. If you want to identify the different states, you should just make real commits.

If you just want this during your (personal/private) development, you can also make normal commits and then later squash the commits to create a single one if you want to clean it up.

Comment: when you do a squash, where do the commits that comprised the squashed commit go?

Comment: A squash basically does the same as permanently amending a single commit does. It creates a new commit object where all the changes from the other individual commits are combined. Afterwards, if no additional references (branches, tags) point to those commits, they may be automatically removed.

Comment: *WHY* would someone do this??

Comment: @PaulHodges Because it’s a useful practice to keep the version history clean.